# Setting up Single sign on to login to different ASP.Net applications in different domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

We have three different applications running on ASP.Net 4.0 and SQLServer 2008, the username/password etc to these applications are stored in user tables in the respective database separately (not forms/windows authentication). An user may have access to all three applications or only one. Currently if the user has access to all applications he has to login separately to each application, logout and login again to another application. Our boss wants make it as a single login page where the user can login and depending on the privilege he has the respective application icons should be shown, when he logout from that application without login again he should be able to access the other application. 
I thought of creating a common table which will have all loginid and passwords from three applications, and create a wrapper application in which the credentials will be captured. First the username will be checked in the common login table and depending on the application access he has, the respective database and application will be invoked. My issue is currently when user login separately to the application few session parameters are passed. When I write a wrapper for common login how do I maintain these session parameters. Also is it possible to maintain session timeout All three applications are in different sub domains in same server. Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can not do much with asp.net session - I suggest to save on a table of yours that data, pass them with your custom code where you handle the login